# Android Px To Dp Working Example?

Tags: android, pixel

I have gone through a lot of tutorials and seen a lot of online converters but this subject this confuses me so I would like to ask for a working example if that is OK.

I have a small image of a ball that is 190px x 190px

I want to scale the image for 
ldpi (120dp)
mdpi (160dp)
hdpi (240dp)
xhdpi (320dp)

Now my first dumb question is this

on converters like 
http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

What do I enter for px ? In my case I have 190px 190px so I assume I enter 190px but lets say width or height is different? what should I input?

My second question is do I need to know the DP in advance? I mean on this converter it says input PX @ at relative DP unit and when I input 190px @ HDPI it says for HDPI it should be 190px ? Which is confusing me since it is saying the image as it is ideal for this generalised DP? Help please!

Comment: I enter Width and Height PX?

Comment: You should based all your calculation on mdpi. For that converter, you have to manually input width, then height then record all the size in px. Lastly, I found [Android Asset Tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example) very useful for this kind of work.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks that Android Asset Tool is a lifesaver. Ah I see so in future I should put my image PX in mdpi first and then record all sizes for each generalised scale

Answer (score 0):

You can convert px to dp:

Get the image size and apply the model below:

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```